# Fix catkin workspace, can't launch newly compiled nodes

Tags: catkin-make, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm having issues running new modules, the compilation goes right but rosrun can't find the new nodes, i guess it's en environment issue, but as I'm a noob, it's just a guess :)

I have the catkin ws under `~/ros_ws/`, in this folder i have my package pcltest, that have a single source file `src/pcltest_node.cpp`
When i run catkin_make i can see the compilation having success:

```
...
[100%] Building CXX object pcltest/CMakeFiles/pcltest_node.dir/src/pcltest_node.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable pcltest_node
[100%] Built target pcltest_node
...
```

And I can find my binary compiled in `~/ros_ws/build/pcltest/pcltest_node`

This is the output of `catkin_make install`

```
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/_setup_util.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/env.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/setup.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/setup.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/setup.zsh
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/.rosinstall
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/pcltest.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/share/pcltest/cmake/pcltestConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/share/pcltest/cmake/pcltestConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/cesare/ros_ws/install/share/pcltest/package.xml
```

then usually I source  `/home/cesare/ros_ws/install/setup.bash` but when i try to run the node with `rosrun pcltest xxx` i have an error, it looks like it's not copying the binary from the build to the install folder... what am I doing wrong ?

----- ----- ----- EDIT ----- ----- -----
I've tried to source `/home/cesare/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash` but it doesn't change much.
In both the cases rosrun is able to find (and autocoplete) the package but it can't find che binary :(

This is how it looks my 'devel/share' dir

```
.
└── pcltest
    └── cmake
        ├── pcltestConfig.cmake
        └── pcltestConfig-version.cmake
```

This is the install/share dir

```
.
└── pcltest
    ├── cmake
    │   ├── pcltestConfig.cmake
    │   └── pcltestConfig-version.cmake
    └── package.xml
```

This is the package in the build dir

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 cesare cesare   4096 giu 18 10:46 .
drwxrwxr-x  8 cesare cesare   4096 giu 18 10:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 cesare cesare   4096 giu 18 10:46 catkin_generated
drwxrwxr-x 47 cesare cesare   4096 giu 18 10:46 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 cesare cesare   2280 giu 18 10:46 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r--  1 cesare cesare    277 giu 18 10:46 CTestTestfile.cmake
-rw-rw-r--  1 cesare cesare  41872 giu 18 10:46 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x  1 cesare cesare 466725 giu 18 10:46 pcltest_node
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pcltest)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
#add_executable(pcltest src/pcltest.cpp) #in this position doesn't work :(
catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


add_executable(pcltest src/pcltest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pcltest
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211548/fix-catkin-workspace,-can%27t-launch-newly-compiled-nodes/) by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-17**:
Does it work if you source devel/ ? What is your cmake file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-18**:
You still haven't shown us your `CMakeLists.txt`, as @dornhege asked. Binary targets need to be `install(..)`-ed, they will not automagically appear in your install space.

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-18**:
Sorry, I didn't understood you wanted the CMakeList.txt, posted :)
Now works, I found the problem (but I don't understand), apparently it was caused by `add_executable` being called to early in the CMakeList (see comment in file)... however I like to know more about the `install(..)` ^_^

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-18**:
Reading http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt :)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-18**:
Binaries end up in devel/lib/. They should have been built there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> then usually I source `/home/cesare/ros_ws/install/setup.bash` but when i try to run the node with `rosrun pcltest xxx` i have an error, it looks like it's not copying the binary from the build to the install folder... what am I doing wrong ?

If you really must use the *install space*, you'll need to add the required `install(..)` statements to your `CMakeLists.txt`. See [catkin 0.6.14 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Building and installing C++ executables](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_executables.html) for more info on that.

As @dornhege mentioned, all binaries will always also end up in `/path/to/catkin_ws/devel/lib/<pkg>`, so if you source `/path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, you should be able to start your node, even without having an `install(..)` statement in your build script.

---

Edit:

> Now works, I found the problem (but I don't understand), apparently it was caused by add_executable being called to early in the CMakeList (see comment in file).. [..]

Ordering of statements in `CMakeLists.txt` files is *very important*. This is not ROS and / or catkin specific, normal CMake can also do <del>strange</del> unexpected things if you don't setup your scripts correctly.

See [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt - Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering) for an overview of the order of statements for catkin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-18**:
Thank you for all the help, i found my way out :) actually i don't think i need install() :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-18**:
For your test pkg you probably don't need it, the `devel` space should be enough. If you ever want to release your pkg though, you'll need to install all nodes, libraries and other files (launch files, meshes, etc). Otherwise they won't be packaged into the `.deb` or `.rpm`.